# AngularJS - Remove table row after object destroyed

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that returns a list of json objects and I iterate through those objects and place them into a table.

Each item on the table has a "Delete" button with an ng-click method:

```
<td><a ng-click="testButton()" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</a></td>
```

I am using ng-resource to delete the object - and that works fine.

However, I want to also be able to hide (or remove) the row that houses the object and the delete button after it is deleted - preferably by using **JQuery**.

Here is my destroy method:

```
$scope.destroyThing = function() {
        $scope.thing= this.thing;
        $scope.thing.$destroy();
        $(this.thing).closest("tr").hide(); // something like this maybe
    }
```

The method destroys the object just fine - it just doesn't remove the row... so I tried logging the object returned when I click the button:

```
$scope.testButton = function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
```

That seems to return the angular Scope object itself - but I can't find a way to access any of the DOM elements that it relates to.

Here is a screenshot to show you the object returned from the testButton function - which is triggered by clicking the button of course:

[image]

**How can I access DOM elements related to the Angular object with JQuery?**

### EDIT

Here is the complete table row:

```
<tr ng-repeat="franchise in franchises">
                <td ng-model="franchiseName">{{franchise.franchise_name}}</td>
                <td ng-model="franchiseNumber">{{franchise.franchise_number}}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-mini">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a ng-click="destroyFranchise()" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</a></td>

            </tr>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't want to access the DOM from the controller. That's against the Zen of Angular :-D

Use `ng-hide` directive:

```
<td><a ng-click="hide()" ng-hide="isHidden">Delete</a></td>
```

And the controller just change the model value, that `ng-hide` is bound to (in this case `isHidden` property).

How do you populate the table ? Are you using `ng-repeat` ? If so, it's enough to just remove the item from the collection that `ng-repeat` repeats over and the DOM will be updated automatically.

Check out  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuiHuZq_cg4

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the hide directive - I will look for the docs on that.  I am using ng-repeat, but when I delete the model, the data for the model disappears and the empty row along with the buttons are left still on the screen.  I added the code I'm using on the row to my original post up top.

Comment: There's something wrong, if you remove the model, ng-repeat should remove the DOM element, can you send a simple example to jsfiddle ? You can start from this http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/una6x/

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking a look.  I made a fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/qNB2C/6/.  I made the app with a Rails backend and put a sample of it on Heroku if you want to checkout the behavior for yourself:  http://high-robot-3535.herokuapp.com/franchise_sets/2/edit.  Feel free to add and delete "franchises".  Notice that when you save a new one, it updates the UI properly.  But when you delete one, it removes the data but does not update the UI.

Comment: Honestly, you are doing lot of crazy stuff. Check out this simplified version. I removed the server-side communication to make it simpler. The point is: there is no DOM manipulation, no scope $destroying, etc... you just work with the model, and let Angular do the hard work... http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/qNB2C/8/

Answer (score 2):

While messing directly with the DOM is not the Angular way, for the people coming from Google that still need to do this, to pass the DOM element to an existing jQuery plugin or something:

1. Use [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.com)'s jQuery Passthrough (recommended)
2. Write an [Angular directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and wrap the DOM handling in there. A starting point: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mJ4sr/).

Answer (score 0):

Make your tableRowClicked method take the row as a argument.

```
<tbody id= "table_row">
 <tr ng-repeat="row in rows" ng-click="tableRowClicked(row)">
    <td ng-repeat="col in row">{{col}}</td>
</tr>
```